# VSTS - Test -> Runs -> Query endpoint is not filtering based on parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm attempting to use the Test -> Runs -> Query endpoint to return a list of test runs for a particular release, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/runs/query)

Unfortunately whatever I put in as a query parameter (with the exception of `$top` which does appear to filter), I appear to get every test run returned against the project.

For example, I know there are 14 test runs against a particular release.

[image]

I can get my release id with the following query...

`https://smartassessor.vsrm.visualstudio.com/Smart End Point Assessment/_apis/release/releases?searchText=Release-103`

If I then try to use that id in the test run query like this...

`https://smartassessor.visualstudio.com/Smart End Point Assessment/_apis/test/runs?releaseIds=1678&api-version=5.0-preview.2`

I get 529 results, which looks like most of the test runs agains the project.

Are the filters working against this endpoint? If so, how should I tweak my request to utilize the `releaseIds` parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue. Seems the APIs are not available for now.

There is [**an issue submitted here**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/242517/filter-parameters-are-not-available-when-query-run.html) for tracking this. You can also track the updates on it.

As a workaround, you can use below PowerShell script to filter the test runs by Release ID: (Alternately you can export the result to a ***.CSV** file)

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com", 
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$releaseid = "1",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

#Set the path and name for the output csv file
$path = "D:\temp"
$filename = "ReleaseTestRun" + "-" + $releaseid


# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/test/runs"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$testruns = $response.value 
Write-Host $results

$Releaseruns = @()

foreach ($testrun in $testruns)
{
$testrunID = $testrun.id
$runbaseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/test/runs/$testrunID"
$runresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $runbaseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} | Where {$_.release.id -eq $releaseid} #| Filter the test run by Release ID

$customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "id" = $runresponse.id
          "name" = $runresponse.name
          "url" = $runresponse.url
          "isAutomated" = $runresponse.isAutomated
          "state" = $runresponse.state
          "totalTests" = $runresponse.totalTests
          "incompleteTests" = $runresponse.incompleteTests
          "notApplicableTests" = $runresponse.notApplicableTests
          "passedTests" = $runresponse.passedTests
          "unanalyzedTests" = $runresponse.unanalyzedTests
          "revision" = $runresponse.revision
          "webAccessUrl" = $runresponse.webAccessUrl
        } 

    $Releaseruns += $customObject
}

$Releaseruns | Select `
                id,
                name,
                url,
                isAutomated,
                state,
                totalTests,
                incompleteTests,
                notApplicableTests,
                passedTests,
                unanalyzedTests,
                revision,
                webAccessUrl | where {$_.id -ne $Null} #|export-csv -Path $path\$filename.csv -NoTypeInformation # Filter non-empty values and export to csv file.
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this code to work. It just loops round an error in the foreach looop `Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Test run with id 3925 could not be found. It may have been 
deleted.`